# Migrations detected wherease makemigrations/migrate already done (and database changed already applied)

Tags: django, docker, database-migration

stack: Django/Docker/Postgresql

I have made some changes in database models last month and deployed in preprod.

```
- remove fields 
- add fields
- alter one field constraint
```

All seems to be correct, changes were applied and app was running.

Yesterday, I've made some minor changes and re-deployed but when I re-build my project, new migrations are detected.
These migrations are exactly the same as above.
And migrate failed because trying to remove a field that did not exist anymore.

Django app update procedure:

```
- sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.preprod.yml down -v
- git pull
- sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.preprod.yml up -d --build --remove-orphans #<= error raise
- sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.preprod.yml up
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

python manage.py makemigrations --noinput
python manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entrypoint must absolutely not have `makemigrations` in it. If you have been running with this in production, you may be screwed (i.e. you'll have migrations in your production database that are to be found nowhere else).

`makemigrations` must *only* be run at development time, and those migrations must be committed to source control.

Comment: thanks for replying. I did not deployed in prod so I can make changes before

Comment: I recommend you to look at your production's `django_migrations` table and compare it to your development version's copy. If there are migrations in one that aren't in the other, you may be in trouble.

Comment: I have checked, and 3 migrations are applied in dev database that are not in prod database because I did not push migrations files ; So if I commit theses 3 migration files, pull and re-build my app it should be ok right?

Comment: Well, should be ok so long as you end up in a situation where your prod and dev database have the same migrations – and you can also compare the current SQL schemas to make sure the actual tables are the same.